# Authentication while scraping via BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have created a piece of code to scrape an article off the ft.com website.

```
url = ""
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
for a in soup.find_all('div', {"id":"storyContent"}):
    print a
```

**1) On the website, there is a div tag with id:storyContent but I get no output as a result of this code which means that it didn' enter the loop at all! What might the reason be?**
Now ft.com does not give access to articles without entering username and password.
I have logged into ft.com using chrome.
Suppose my username, password details are the following:
Username : bs@sb.com
Pass: 12345
I need to know either of the following:
**2) How can I provide this authentication in my code?

3) How can I use the session on chrome (on which I'm already logged in) to acces the webpage/article details.

4) If authentication is the resson behind no output!

5) I am trying to get the article's body out of the webpage.**
Thanks!

Comment: use python mechanize for authentication and fetch the source and then use beautiful soup

Comment: mechanize is no longer supported.

Comment: Try and get the form, then you can submit with `r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data = {'key':'value'})`

Comment: @DanielLee, if you could help me with one more little thing please. I am trying to extract the p tags within the div tags for div in soup.find_all('div', {"id":"storyContent"}): and then for p in div.find_all('p'): print p.string. There are certain p tags that also contain anchors. So the p.string returns a None. How do I get the entire article out? Thanks!

Comment: try using `for p in div.get_text() print p`

Comment: I just tried that before seeing your comment. I was using p.string before this, it didn't yield the apt result! Thanks again!

Comment: `for div in soup.find_all('div', {"id":"storyContent"}):  
    for p in div.find_all('p'):  
        print p.text`

Comment: try `for div in soup.find_all('div', {"id":"storyContent"}) print div.get_text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather start with this.

```
url = "http://www.ft.com"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
for a in soup:
    print a
```

Then add a requests when you find the key:value pair required

```
r = requests.post('http://www.ft.com/xxx', data = {'key':'value'})
```